# How to make image 3D using CSS

Tags: html, css

I draw chess board with the help of html table now I want to make it 3D here is my css and html.

```css
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: black;
}
td {
  width: 60px; height: 60px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white;
  width: 59px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table height="488" width="460" style="display:inline-block;border-style:double">
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Current Result:
[image]

Want to make it like:

[image]

Comment: have you tried perspective and transform rotate -> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

Comment: yes but i am not understanding how to make it like like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you want that it looks a little bit more 3D than you can take the code from @haxxxton and add a div at the bottom like below.

```css
table {
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 background: black;
 border:2px double black;
}
td {
 width: 60px; height: 60px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
 background: white;
 width: 59px;
 height: 59px;
}
.parent {
 margin:0 auto;
 height:488px;
 width:460px;
 perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
 perspective: 1000px;
}
.child {
 transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
#div3 { 
  position: relative;
    height: 10px;
    width: 616px;
    margin-left:-61px;
    margin-top:-90px;
    background-color: brown;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <table class="child" height="488" width="488">
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 </table> 
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```css
.parent {
  margin: -100px auto;
  width: 460px;
  height: 488px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #533E29;
}
td {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #BC8D5E;
  width: 59px;
  height: 50px;
}
.board-border {
  transform: rotateX(60deg);
  background: #96715F;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 3px 2px #333;
  width: 470px;
  height: 498px;
}
.board-border:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 460px;
  height: 488px;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  /* overlay styles */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 61%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 195, 130, 0.33) 0%, rgba(255, 195, 130, 0.33) 40%, rgba(255, 195, 130, 0) 70%, rgba(255, 195, 130, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="board-border">
    <table height="488" width="460">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent Sir,this is excatly what I mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Naturally, it is difficult to achieve the full 3D effect. I could achieve a *similar* effect using:

- `transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);` - a perspective effect.
- [`background: radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) - for the soft lighting effect.
- Transparent light square, so the background effect is visible.
- On-hover animation effect, just to demonstrate how it behaves.

```css
table {
  margin: 0 120px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 70% 90%,#8A6A4A,#4E3A27);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(45deg);
  transition: 0.8s;
}
table:hover {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(60deg) rotateY(-5deg);
}

td {
  width: 28px; height: 28px; border:none;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(255,195,130,0.3);
}
```

```html
<table style="display:inline-block;border-style:double">
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `perspective` and `rotateX` you can achieve what you're after. Also moved the table styling into the stylesheet and fixed the border.

PS. updated to make the chessboard squares square

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r790jfpy/1/)**

**CSS**

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: black;
    border:2px double black;
}
td {
    width: 60px; height: 60px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even),
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: white;
    width: 59px;
    height: 59px;
}
.parent {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:488px;
    width:460px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.child {
    transform: rotateX(60deg);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <table class="child" height="488" width="488">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```